# To pay to be kind

Tags: idioms

"it really pays to be kind" ,  is this expression a structure or an idiom in English?
Can you say it pays to be [something] too or not?

Comment: Of course, you can say "it pays to be honest," "it pays to study hard," "it pays to be cautious," and so on.

Comment: I would say it's just usage, not an idiom.

Comment: is it the same to say: it pays to be nice AND it's a worth to be nice ??

Comment: I'd say “it's worth it to be nice.” In that structure “worth it” means “worth the effort.”

Answer (score 3):

"It pays to [x]" = one benefits eventually if one makes a habit of doing x.